# Does this system of matrix equations with diagonal restrictions have an analytical solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, symmetric-matrices, positive-definite

The following matrices are all $n\times n$ and real.

$A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ are unknown.  Moreover, $D$ is diagonal, and $diag(D)=diag(B)$.  $A$ and $C$ are both positive definite.

$\Sigma_{11}$, $\Sigma_{21}$ and $\Sigma_{22}$ are all known.  $\Sigma_{11}$ and $\Sigma_{22}$ are positive definite.

These matrices satisfy the following:

$\Sigma_{11} = BAB' + DCD'$

$\Sigma_{21} = BA +  DC $

$\Sigma_{22} = A + C$

The unknown matrices have $2n^2 + n$ independent entries ($B$ has $n^2$, $A$ and $C$ each have $\frac{n^2+n}{2}$, and the $n$ entries of $D$ are found on the diagonal of $B$). Because of the symmetric structures, the matrix equations are really $\frac{n(n+1)}{2} + n^2 +\frac{n(n+1)}{2} = 2n^2 + n$ scalar equations, so I suspect that this has a solution.  (I also suspect that the solution is unique up to signs/reordering for the $n>1$ case.)

I am interested in solving for $B$ ($A$ and $C$ are unimportant).  I can do so in the scalar case where $n=1$, but am stumped when $n>1$.  Any ideas?  If necessary, we can assume $B$ or $\Sigma_{21}$ are invertible, but I would prefer not to.

Thanks!

Comment: The existence and uniqueness without further conditions seems a bit optimistic. In the scalar case ($n=1$), we must have $D=B$, then $A+C=B^{-2}\Sigma_{11}=B^{-1}\Sigma_{21}=\Sigma_{22}$. Not unique, and not possible either if the conditions on $\Sigma_{ij}$ are not met.